# What is equivilent of the code below in Reflection.Emit IL

Tags: .net, reflection, cil, reflection.emit, il

```
void DoSomething(Data data){
    var myDataRequest = new DataRequest();
    myDataRequest.ID = data.ID
}
```

I have the following

```
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getMethodForData);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setMethodForDataRequest);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
```

But it does not seem to work

Code, I really want to generate:

```
static Response TestRequestResponse(RequestData requestData) {
            var wrapper = new WrapperResponse<Response>();
            var request = new Request() { };
            request.RequestID = requestData.RequestID;
            request.Value = requestData.Value;
            request.ID = requestData.ID;
            request.OnReply(wrapper.Handle);
            request.WaitForResponse(true);
            request.TimeOut(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            request.Send();
            return wrapper.Response;
        }
```

I have the following code here: [http://pservicebusext.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4f8a4f1190ae#PServiceBus.RemoteProxy%2fPServiceBus.RemoteProxy%2fESBProxy.cs](http://pservicebusext.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4f8a4f1190ae#PServiceBus.RemoteProxy/PServiceBus.RemoteProxy/ESBProxy.cs)

There is a method called CreateProxy() which suppose to generate the code above. But the part loops and generate the get and set for the method is not working properly. It never set the values of request object, it is always left as null

I solved the problem, I changed from using OpCodes.Ldarg_0 to OpCodes.Ldarg_1

```
methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getMethodForData);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setMethodForDataRequest);
 methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
```

Comment: If you are using .net 4 then you can compile method based on expression tree, that is easy to create.

Comment: The reason i am using reflection.emit is because I am generating a class based on an interface methods. Expression Tree would not fit in this situation.

Comment: I think you can compile an expression tree into an existing methodbuilder. That might allow you to implement an interface.

Comment: Looking at the link to the code I posted, would it be possible to convert it to an expression tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, compile your method and use some decompiler (Reflector or even LINQPad) to read the IL. I got the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      DataRequest..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldarg.1     
IL_0008:  callvirt    Data.get_ID
IL_000D:  callvirt    DataRequest.set_ID
IL_0012:  ret
```

**EDIT:** The following code works for me:

```
public class DataRequest
{
    public DataRequest()
    {}

    private int m_id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return m_id; }
        set { m_id = value; }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    private int m_id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return m_id; }
        set { m_id = value; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("DoSomething", typeof(void), new[] { typeof(Data) });
        var methodIL = method.GetILGenerator();
        var constructor = typeof(DataRequest).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        var getMethodForData = typeof(Data).GetProperty("ID").GetGetMethod();
        var setMethodForDataRequest = typeof(DataRequest).GetProperty("ID").GetSetMethod();
        methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructor);
        // storing and loading the same object to the some local is useless
        //var dataReuqest = methodIL.DeclareLocal(typeof(DataRequest));
        //methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, dataReuqest.LocalIndex);
        //methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, dataReuqest.LocalIndex);
        methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getMethodForData);
        methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setMethodForDataRequest);
        methodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var f = (Action<Data>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Data>));
        var data = new Data { ID = 42 };
        f(data);
    }
}
```

Maybe you forgot to declare the local variables you're using?

Comment: That is the same code that I have, above too. I only showed the reflection.emit code get and set. I have the newobj already and it does not still work

Comment: How does it not work? What *does* it do? How do you use the emited code?

Comment: look at the changes I made to the original post for what I am referring to

Comment: I noticed you don't have OpCodes.Ldloc been used. I will try it out

Comment: Still does not work. And looking at the code you posted. It will do something different from what I want. 

new DataRequest().ID = data.ID

Comment: The code, i currently have is suppose to do that for multiple properties. That is why I have a for loop to generate the IL codes. if the value of the DataRequest is not stored in a local variable then multiple variable will not be possible.

Comment: I have locals declared. The code I am refering to is in the original post link of codeplex